# How to do background processing in MonoMac

Tags: c#, mono, monomac, xamarin.mac

I just started using MonoMac. I have a small window with a window which contains a button and a label, if I click the button a process is started (executing an loop) til the loop is finished, the UI is locked, but I'd like to update the label (or a progress bar in the future) on each round in the loop. What have I to do that such an (asynchronous) workflow works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your code will all be running on the UI thread so there is no way for you to report progress because the thread is busy processing your loop. MonoMac has [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) support so you should be able to leverage it to run your code in the background

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    for (...) 
    {
        ...
        // update UI
        uiControl.BeginInvoke(() => {
            uiControl.Text = "Updated from thread";
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. But I noticed that during the process my app boosts to 95% CPU usage.

Comment: Right, I got it, my notification where in the wrong location. Thank you again,